# Do the equalities $\int_0^∞1dx·\int _0^∞1dx=2\int_0^∞xdx$ and $\int_0^∞e^xdx·\int_0^∞e^xdx=2\int_0^∞e^{2 x}dx-2\int_0^∞e^xdx$ make sense?

Tags: intuition, divergent-integrals

Previously I tried to define multiplication of divergent integrals, but my approach turned out to be umbral-like.

Now, I decided to define multiplication of divergent integrals in a Hardy fields-like manner but explicitly without infinitesimals (so that the divergent integrals that have partial sums approaching each other to be considered equal, just like we do with convergent improper integrals).

Here is the formula:

$\int _0^{\infty }f(x)dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }g(x)dx=\frac{1}{4} \left(\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](0)-\mathcal{L}_t[f(-t)](0)\right) \left(\mathcal{L}_t[g(t)](0)-\mathcal{L}_t[g(-t)](0)\right)+\int_0^\infty D_x\left(\int_0^x f(t) \, dt \cdot\int_0^x g(t) \, dt\right)dx-\mathcal{L}_x[D_x\left(\int_0^x f(t) \, dt \cdot\int_0^x g(t) \, dt\right)](0)$

It works with convergent integrals as well.

Here is the Mathematica code:

```
f[x_] := Exp[x]
g[x_] := Exp[x]
ni := 1/4 (LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, v] - 
     LaplaceTransform[f[-t], t, v]) (LaplaceTransform[g[t], t, v] - 
     LaplaceTransform[g[-t], t, v]) /. v -> 0 /. ComplexInfinity -> 0 // Quiet
prod2[x_] := 
 Evaluate[Refine[
    Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, x}] Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, x}], x > 0] // 
   FullSimplify]
Inactivate[
    Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
      g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], Integrate] == 
   FullSimplify[
    ni + Distribute[
      Integrate[
       ExpandAll[FullSimplify[D[prod2[x], x]]], {x, 
        0, \[Infinity]}]] - (FullSimplify[
           LaplaceTransform[Evaluate[D[prod2[t], t]], t, o] /. o -> 0] /. 
          ComplexInfinity -> 0 /. \[Infinity] -> 0 /. -\[Infinity] -> 
         0  /. Indeterminate -> C )]// 
  ExpandAll // Quiet
Inactivate[
  Reg[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
     g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], Integrate] == FullSimplify[ni]
```

The program also finds the regularized value of the product.
This gives the following results:

$\int _0^{\infty }e^xdx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }e^xdx=\int_0^{\infty } -2 e^x \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } 2 e^{2 x} \, dx$

$\text{Reg}\left(\int _0^{\infty }e^xdx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }e^xdx\right)=1$

---

$\int _0^{\infty }1dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }1dx=\int_0^{\infty } 2 x \, dx$

$\text{Reg}\left(\int _0^{\infty }1dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }1dx\right)=0$

---

$\int _0^{\infty }xe^x dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }e^xdx=\int_0^{\infty } e^x \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } -e^{2 x} \, dx-\int_0^{\infty } e^x x \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } 2 e^{2 x} x \, dx$

$\text{Reg}\left(\int _0^{\infty }e^x xdx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }e^xdx\right)=-1$

---

$\int _0^{\infty }e^xdx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }e^{2 x}dx=-\int_0^{\infty } e^{2 x} \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } 2 e^{2 x} \sinh (x) \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } e^{2 x} \cosh (x) \, dx$

$\text{Reg}\left(\int _0^{\infty }e^xdx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }e^{2 x}dx\right)=\frac{1}{2}$

---

$\int _0^{\infty }1dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }xdx=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{3 x^2}{2} \, dx$

$\text{Reg}\left(\int _0^{\infty }1dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }xdx\right)=0$

---

$\int _0^{\infty }e^{a  x}dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }e^{b x}dx=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{a  x+x b}}{a } \, dx-\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{x b}}{a } \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{a  x+x b}}{b} \, dx-\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{a  x}}{b} \, dx$

$\text{Reg}\left(\int _0^{\infty }e^{a  x}dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }e^{b x}dx\right)=\frac{1}{ab}$

etc.

Thus I wonder whether these results can be intuitively justified based on other considerations or methods?

Comment: UPDATE. I fixed the formulas, the code and the results, these were wrong.